# selecting the row with given datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

There are 2 datasets I wanna use to find the evaluation score which `data_pred` , `data_test`

First of all, the `data_test` is the data that is used to check the accuracy which looks like this

[image: data_test]

the `data_pred` is got from ARIMA prediction which looks ​like this

[image]

The reason I can't find the MSE score between these 2 datasets is that the number of rows is not equal, since the `data_pred` predicted every single by the range of the starting date to the end date of the test set.

So, My question is how to select the `data_pred` instance which has the same index as `data_test`

P.s. date is the index of both dataset

Comment: use `pd.merge` to combine them by common date and then take mse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
df2.set_index('date').subtract(df.set_index('date')).dropna().pow(2).sum().values[0]
```

---

[image]